# Why does defining properties on process.env leads to strange conditional branching?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to test some code that does different things depending on the environment. I thought I might be able to modify properties on `process.env` in my tests (although I thought it might be a bad idea), but I realized I get this really odd behavior:

```
let foo = function(inp) {
  if (inp) {
    console.log(inp + ' -> if')
  } else {
    console.log(inp + ' -> else')
  }
}

// property starts undefined
foo(process.env.prop)
    // undefined -> else

process.env.prop = true
foo(process.env.prop)
    // true -> if

process.env.prop = false
foo(process.env.prop)
    // false -> if          !!!

process.env.prop = undefined
foo(process.env.prop)
    // undefined -> if      !!!

delete(process.env.prop)
foo(process.env.prop)
    // undefined -> else
```

I expected that setting `process.env.prop = false` would have caused the `else` branch to execute, not the `if` branch. If I use properties on new objects, I do get the behavior I expect (Link to REPL demonstrating this: https://repl.it/@JustinKulikausk/TechnologicalThickMuse).

Has anyone else experienced this? I'm really hoping for some insight into why this is happening, not just a workaround for my tests.

Comment: i think that happens because of falsy values https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Props are strings. From [the docs (v10.4.1)](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/docs/api/process.html#process_process_env)

> Assigning a property on process.env will implicitly convert the value to a string. This behavior is deprecated. Future versions of Node.js may throw an error when the value is not a string, number, or boolean.

Your `false` is converted to `'false'` which is "truthy" as it is a valid string of length 5. Same with keyword `undefined`. Your `delete` is legit. I'm not sure which part is deprecated, but the behavior you describe looks like it is working as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much! As a consequence of this, it looks like I can get a falsy value (which I needed) by assigning an empty string to the property.